# Asp.net master/content page caching problem

Tags: asp.net

On my master page is repeater control, which basically puts together my site navigation.  It is driven by an ObjectDataSource with caching enabled, it uses SqlCacheDependency to notify itself when a page is added or removed from the database.

Now, on my content page, i am using the following:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="999999" VaryByParam="slug" SqlDependency="SiteDataCaching:MenuHeaders" %>
```

And then access my dl to put together the pages title, content, metadescription etc etc.

The content page will refresh the cache no worries, but for some reason, if i am on page that has the OutputCache enabled, my menu on the masterpage won't update itself unless i forcefully hit ctrl+f5.

Anyone know why this is?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this articles.. I hope they will help.

[@ OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx)

[OutputCache - more examples](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/caching/more-output-cache/)

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/aspnet/syntax/outputcache.aspx

[ASP.NET Page Output Cache](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/OutputCache.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hitting CTRL-F5 is a clientside action, so I would say that you've got the page you're looking at cached in your webbrowser. Try setting `<%@ OutputCache Location="Server" ... %>` to deny clientside caching.